# find the local time zone’s difference from GMT in minutes

Tags: c++, linux, c++17, timezone-offset, c++-chrono

I have timezone in format GMT+09:00 and GMT+10:00. I am using Linux (Open Suse) and C++17. 
I am trying to find out the local time zone’s difference from GMT in minutes.

Here is my sample program.

```
static constexpr time_t const NULL_TIME = -1;

// returns difference in mintues
long tz_offset(time_t when = NULL_TIME) {
  if (when == NULL_TIME)
    when = std::time(nullptr);
  auto const tm = *std::localtime(&when);
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << std::put_time(&tm, "%z");
  std::string s = os.str();
  // s is in ISO 8601 format: "±HHMM"
  int h = std::stoi(s.substr(0, 3), nullptr, 10);
  int m = std::stoi(s[0] + s.substr(3), nullptr, 10);
  return h * 60 + m;
}

int main() {
  for (auto &timezone :  {"GMT+08:00", "GMT+09:30", "GMT+10:00", "GMT+10:30", "GMT+11:00"}) {
    setenv("TZ", timezone, 1);
    tzset();
    std::cout << "----------- TZ Changed to " << timezone << "---------------\n";
    std::cout << "difference in mins =" << tz_offset() << std::endl;
    auto tz_env_var = getenv("TZ");
    if (tz_env_var != nullptr) {
      std::cout << "TZ=" << tz_env_var << "\n";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the difference in the negative, they should be positive.

```
----------- TZ Changed to GMT+08:00---------------
difference in mins =-480
TZ=GMT+08:00
----------- TZ Changed to GMT+09:30---------------
difference in mins =-570
TZ=GMT+09:30
----------- TZ Changed to GMT+10:00---------------
difference in mins =-600
TZ=GMT+10:00
----------- TZ Changed to GMT+10:30---------------
difference in mins =-630
TZ=GMT+10:30
----------- TZ Changed to GMT+11:00---------------
difference in mins =-660
TZ=GMT+11:00
```

Any pointer why I am getting them in the negative?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you allowed to use?

Comment: I am using C++17

Comment: It is by definition. The offsets you have in the strings are the opposite of the offsets given by the `tz_offset()` function.  Look at the manual pages.  The reason of this is that both standards (the way of writing timezones and the definition of the `tz_offset()` function) originate from different, unrelated, places.  If you consider european timezones (like `GMT-03:00` here) you'll see positive `tz_offset()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These strings are known as *POSIX timezones* and are [defined here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).  This definition says this about the UTC offset:

> If preceded by a '-', the timezone shall be east of the Prime Meridian; otherwise, it shall be west (which may be indicated by an optional preceding '+' ).

Meanwhile `std::put_time` is defined in terms of the C/Posix `strftime` which says this about offset:

> %z is replaced by the offset from UTC in the ISO 8601 format ‘‘−0430’’ (meaning 4
>   hours 30 minutes behind UTC, west of Greenwich), or by no characters if no time
>   zone is determinable. [tm_isdst]

In summary, there's one convention for posix time zone strings (negative means **east** of the prime meridian), and another for just about everyone else, including other parts of posix (negative means **west** of the prime meridian).

So your code is actually getting the correct answer.

Fwiw, here is a [C++17 free, open-source, header-only Posix time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/ptz.h) which can to the job without changing the global environment variable `TZ`, and does it with simpler syntax:

```
#include "date/ptz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using date::operator<<;

    for (auto &timezone : {"GMT+08:00", "GMT+09:30", "GMT+10:00", "GMT+10:30", "GMT+11:00"})
    {
        auto offset = Posix::time_zone{timezone}.get_info(system_clock::now()).offset;
        std::cout << "difference is " << duration_cast<minutes>(offset) << '\n';
        std::cout << "TZ is " << timezone << "\n\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
difference is -480min
TZ is GMT+08:00

difference is -570min
TZ is GMT+09:30

difference is -600min
TZ is GMT+10:00

difference is -630min
TZ is GMT+10:30

difference is -660min
TZ is GMT+11:00
```

Comment: Thanks, @Howard Hinnant for the explanation. This means If I need a local time zone difference from GMT for the Australia region then I have to use "GMT-08:00", "GMT-09:30".